# How to prevent a display:flex item from clearing the previous float?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Looks like display:flex item automatically clears the previous float.

How to prevent it from clearing? (I need the previous content to overlap the flex container).

For example:

```css
.floater{
  float:right;
  width: 200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.row{
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:12px;
  width:100%;
  clear:none;
}
.col-400{
  flex-basis:400px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:12px;
}
.col-grow{
  flex-grow:1;
  border:1px solid teal;
  padding:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  Intro content
  <div class='floater'>
    Please float to right. And don't clear.
    Please float to right. And don't clear.
    Please float to right. And don't clear.
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-400'>
      Left col
      Left col
      Left col
      Left col
      Left col
    </div>
    <div class='col-grow'>
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
      Main col
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Looks like this:
[image]

I want red to overlap on green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;`

```
.floater{
    position: absolute;
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Okay.. looks bit hacky but I can go with that. Any idea why flex does this seemingly unnecessary clear?

Comment: quote from w3.org: A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context, except that flex layout is used instead of block layout. For example, floats do not intrude into the flex container, and the flex container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents. Flex containers form a containing block for their contents exactly like block containers do. [CSS21] The overflow property applies to flex containers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with `flex`, this is because of the padding of the flex element increasing the width of the element outside 100%. This is because you have not provided box-sizing to the html add `box-sizing: border-box;` this will make padding expect same as what expected.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.floater {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: none;
}

.col-400 {
    flex-basis: 400px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 12px;
}

.col-grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px solid teal;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
    Intro content
    <div class='floater'>
        Please float to right. And don't clear. Please float to right. And don't clear. Please float to right. And don't clear.
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-400'>
            Left col Left col Left col Left col Left col
        </div>
        <div class='col-grow'>
            Main col Main col Main col Main col Main col Main col Main col Main col Main col Main col
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :-O box-sizing: border-box; was there in my original post... and now it seems its gone after your edit! Anyway, even when it was there I had the "float automatically getting cleared" problem

Comment: @Teddy I haven't removed `box-sizing: border-box;` while editing, you can check the edit details of the post. This is working fine right? Try `Run code snippet` and check that's working or not.

Comment: You're right, you didn't remove it. It seems I added box-sizing after copying the code. But, I took the screenshot after adding box-sizing. My problem is that red content should overlap on green.

Comment: @Teddy can you add the screenshot of your requirement? I hope the image that you added is your requirement. If not can you please add the screenshot?